# jquery-ajax : getting server xml file response in javascript array

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get XML response in javascript array like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrayName = []; 
    var arrayValue  [];
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) { parseXml(xml); }
});
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
    $(xml).find("category").each(function()
    {
        arrayName.push($(this).find("name").text());
        arrayValue.push($(this).find("value").text());
    });
}

 //Do some javascript stuff using arrayName and arrayValue for example:
    alert(arrayName[0]);
    alert(arrayValue[0]);

</script>
```

But I am not able to get xml response in javascript array.

my XML file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <data>
        <category id="category1">
            <name>Error</name>
            <value>41</value>
        </category>
        <category id="category2">
            <name>Warning</name>
            <value>23</value>
        </category>
        <category id="category3">
            <name>Info</name>
            <value>46</value>
        </category> 
    </data>
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: This might already solve your problem: Put the `alert`s in the callback. They are executed before the response comes from the server. Ajax is **asynchronous**.

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for replying. Since I am new to jquery so I dont know how to use callbacks effectively. Can you show me some code snippet for above one.

Answer (score 4):

I will repeat my comment here:

Put the alerts in the callback. They are executed before the response comes from the server. Ajax is **asynchronous**.

So basically you have to call all the code that has to deal with the response from your callback.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {          
            var items = parseXml(xml);
            doStuff(items);
        }
    });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    var items = [];
    $(xml).find("category").each(function() {
        items.push({
            name: $(this).find("name").text(), 
            value: $(this).find("value").text()
        });
    });
    return items;
}

function doStuff(items) {
    //Do some javascript stuff with the response
    alert(items[0].name);
    alert(tiems[0].value);
}
```

Callbacks are nothing special. As functions are first class objects in JavaScript, you can pass them around like any other value.

Comment: @nitin: Please accept the answer then by clicking the tick outline next to it.